# How can I declare the type for a function with properties in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I read some documentation on the TypeScript website, but I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly. In this scenario, I'm using a package that does not have TypeScript types available (`prismic-reactjs`) and so I am trying to declare the types myself so that I can get rid of the errors riddling my project.

So, as a basic example, how would I write the declaration for such a function:

```js
const foo = ({ bar }) =>  {
    return bar;
};

foo.baz = () => "string";
```

I can get this far:

```js
declare module "my-module" {
  interface fooParams {
    bar: string;
  }

  export function foo({ bar }: fooParams): string;
}
```

But how can I include the `baz` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).

```
declare const foo: {
  baz: () => string
} & (({ bar }: {bar: string}) =>  string)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought this would be a good opportunity to learn about how typings are written for existing JavaScript modules (and I can't run `tsc` without errors because the package `prismic-reactjs` doesn't have typings). However, this doesn't look like a type definition (e.g. I'm trying to write `index.d.ts`). Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Basically, the function exists and I can't change it, I just want to write the type definition so that TypeScript doesn't complain, "Could not find a declaration file for module 'prismic-reactjs'"

Comment: This design pattern (functions that also have properties) is quite common especially in the rediscovery days (web2.0) of javascript when it started to be taken as a serious language. Lots of libraries such as jQuery have their main object container be a function (in jQuery's case it is both a regular function and a constructor) that have properties and methods attached to it. So lots of legacy code were written this way and even some modern code continue to be written this way by people from that generation (like myself)

Comment: @Griffen sorry I misunderstood your question, please check my latest answer